# Javafx exception occurs when a method is called passing a observable list

Tags: javafx, charts

I am trying to declare a line chart in javafx and take a screenshot. After adding the data, data series and xAxis and yAxis it is passed to the screenshot method. This exception occurs when trying to call that method.

```
        CategoryAxis monthAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        monthAxis.setLabel("Month");
        NumberAxis profitAxis = new NumberAxis();
        profitAxis.setLabel("Profit");

        String[] monthName = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
        "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

        LineChart profitLineChart = new LineChart(monthAxis, profitAxis);
        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();

        int[] profitValues = new int[monthlyRecords.size()];
        int[] monthNo = new int[monthlyRecords.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < monthlyRecords.size(); i++) {

            profitValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(monthlyRecords.get(i).getProfit());
            monthNo[i] = Integer.parseInt(monthlyRecords.get(i).getMonth());
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(monthName[monthNo[i]-1], profitValues[i]));
        }

        profitLineChart.getData().addAll(series1);
        saveProfitLineChartToFile(monthAxis,profitAxis,series1.getData(), "profitLineChart.png");
```

The method that is being called:

```
   public static void saveProfitLineChartToFile(CategoryAxis monthAxis, NumberAxis profitAxis,ObservableList<LineChart.Data> lineChartData, String path) throws IOException {

    LineChart lineChart = new LineChart(monthAxis,profitAxis,lineChartData);
    Scene sceneForChart = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
    WritableImage image = lineChart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
    File file = new File(path);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The exception that occurs:

```
javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Data cannot be cast to javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series
```

Comment: Check the signature of `LineChart` again. It does not take a `ObservableList<XYChart.Data>` parameter...

Comment: More generally, if you avoid using raw types (e.g. use `LineChart<String, Number>` instead of `LineChart`, `XYChart.Series<String, Number>` instead of `XYChart.Series`, etc etc, the compiler will flag these errors for you, and allow you to fix them before you can run the code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be called as :

```
saveProfitLineChartToFile(monthAxis,profitAxis,profitLineCha‌​rt.getData(), "profitLineChart.png");
```